# Burninate then Blacklist the [tutorial] and [tutorials] tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I feel that the [tutorial](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tutorial) and the [tutorials](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tutorials) tags should be blacklisted.  They are for the most part called out in the FAQ as off topic, and even when they are non general knowledge and cannot be easily answered with a Google search then they have to be monitored very closely for poor answers that contribute nothing but a link to that persons favorite site.

Examples of confusion that we are potentially giving users over the appropriateness of tutorial requests:

[What is the correct UI interface to learn for creating Windows phone 8 apps?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/173605/what-is-the-correct-ui-interface-to-learn-for-creating-windows-phone-8-apps#comment331805_173605)

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/173532/excellent-c-tutorials

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/170525/where-can-i-learn-objective-c-well

[What are the benefits and drawback of documentation vs tutorials vs video tutorials](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/165219/what-are-the-benefits-and-drawback-of-documentation-vs-tutorials-vs-video-tutori)

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/159852/scala-courses-like-codeschool-or-codecademy

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148902/ruby-on-rails-book-with-exercises

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/129444/interactive-tutorial-for-learning-python

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/126027/intro-to-windows-development-for-a-linux-programmer

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/124617/best-tutorial-for-c-asp-net

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/119892/are-there-any-good-books-or-tutorials-on-learning-visual-studio

I could continue to post examples but I think my point is clear.  Nearly all of these questions posted with this tag have been closed, and the ones that aren't were probably just missed.

**EDIT:** Currently no more Closed questions have the tag.

Comment: They need to be burninated before they are blacklisted (also it's the same tag, they are merged).

Comment: Perhaps the community can help edit posts to remove the tag and focus the question if possible, or just flag for moderator attention?

Comment: Well, if I see a flag I'll assume the flagger couldn't come up with any way of salvaging the question, and if I also can't come up with a way, I'll just kill it. From quickly scanning the questions, they all seem extremely off topic, but at least a few might be salvageable if examined more closely.